How do I run the generalTestBF function from the BayesFactor package inside a group_by in a pipe in tidy verse?
I am trying to extract the regression coefficient, p-value, and Bayes Factor for each subset of a data frame in r. I am using tidyverse piping and group_by(), and it works for the regression coefficient and p-value, but not for the BF.
If I try this:
library(tidyverse)
library(BayesFactor)

group<-rep(c(0,1), each=100)
x<-rnorm(200)
y<-(x*group) + rnorm(200)
d<-data.frame(group,x,y)

d %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarise(
    b = summary(lm(y ~ x))$coefficients[2,1],
    p = summary(lm(y ~ x))$coefficients[2,4],
    BF = generalTestBF(y ~ x, whichModels="top")@bayesFactor$bf
  )

I get this error:
Error in `summarise()`:
ℹ In argument: `BF = generalTestBF(y ~ x, whichModels = "top")@bayesFactor$bf`.
ℹ In group 1: `group = 0`.
Caused by error in `generalTestBF()`:
! argument "data" is missing, with no default

I tried adding data = . like this:
d %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarise(
    df = summary(lm(y ~ x))$df[2],
    b = summary(lm(y ~ x))$coefficients[2,1],
    p = summary(lm(y ~ x))$coefficients[2,4],
    BF = generalTestBF(y ~ x, whichModels="top", data=. )@bayesFactor$bf
  )

But the BF is calculated for the entire dataset, not separately by each group. In the table below it gives the same BF for both groups. It also gives the warning message below.
  group    df       b        p    BF
  <dbl> <int>   <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
1     0    98 -0.0493 6.86e- 1 -13.6
2     1    98  0.872  1.44e-14 -13.6

Warning message:
There were 2 warnings in `summarise()`.
The first warning was:
ℹ In argument: `BF = generalTestBF(y ~ x, whichModels = "top", data = .)@bayesFactor$bf`.
ℹ In group 1: `group = 0`.
Caused by warning:
! data coerced from tibble to data frame
ℹ Run dplyr::last_dplyr_warnings() to see the 1 remaining warning. 
> dplyr::last_dplyr_warnings()
[[1]]
<warning/rlang_warning>
Warning in `summarise()`:
ℹ In argument: `BF = generalTestBF(y ~ x, whichModels = "top", data = .)@bayesFactor$bf`.
ℹ In group 1: `group = 0`.
Caused by warning:
! data coerced from tibble to data frame
---
Backtrace:
    ▆
 1. ├─d %>% group_by(group) %>% ...
 2. ├─dplyr::summarise(...)
 3. └─dplyr:::summarise.grouped_df(...)

[[2]]
<warning/rlang_warning>
Warning in `summarise()`:
ℹ In argument: `BF = generalTestBF(y ~ x, whichModels = "top", data = .)@bayesFactor$bf`.
ℹ In group 2: `group = 1`.
Caused by warning:
! data coerced from tibble to data frame
---
Backtrace:
    ▆
 1. ├─d %>% group_by(group) %>% ...
 2. ├─dplyr::summarise(...)
 3. └─dplyr:::summarise.grouped_df(...)



I cant figure out how to get generalTestBF to run separately for each group in the pipe. I want it to give me two separate results like this:
out<-d%>%
  filter(group==0)%>%
  generalTestBF(data=., y ~ x, whichModels="top")
out@bayesFactor$bf

which produces:
[1] 1.556689

and this:
out<-d%>%
filter(group==1)%>%
generalTestBF(data=., y ~ x, whichModels="top")
out@bayesFactor$bf

which produces:
-33.05019

Thanks so much for your help!
